# Going beyond LIKE in searches

Tags: search

Kind of similar to how the "Related Questions" search works here when posting questions: What open source systems exists out there that lets your searches go beyond SQL based LIKE matches? I want to be able to query "he said it" and get results that includes "she said it" (with "said it" being the key, not the semantical meaning of he/she). Again, similar to how my title, "Going beyond LIKE in searches", lists amongst others the question "Going beyond the iframe".

FYI: This is for a Ruby on Rails app. No particular DB engine is required, other than it free/open source (e.g no Oracle, MsSql and so on).

UPDATE: I wish stackoverflow.com would let me accept multiple answers! Kind of hard to pick one for a namedropping question such as this. You have my upvotes, though ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big OS full text search engine I can think of is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/).

I think its search [capabilities](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html) will do what you want.

Comment: Note that Lucene is a Java technology.  Google shows Ferret (http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac/) is a work-alike search engine for Ruby on Rails.  I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Sphinx Search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/).

This is open source software (GPL v2).  It includes an API for Ruby on Rails.

There's at least one other API for Ruby on Rails called [Riddle](http://riddle.freelancing-gods.com/) (get it?  [Riddle of the Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx#The_Riddle_of_the_Sphinx)?  :-).

Comment: Tagged John Nolan's as accepted, cause he needs the rep more than you do ; ) Both good answers, though, thanks!